# GET URL with constant and dynamic params, with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, get-request

I have a GET URL like that:

http://myrestapi.com/?method=search&name=nametosearch&format=json

I've written my service like that:

```
@GET("?method=search")
Observable<List<Album>> getAlbums(@Query("name") String searchedName);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to add `&format=json` at the end.

I've tried:

```
@GET("?method=search&name={searched_name}&format=json")
Observable<List<Album>> getAlbums(@Path("searched_name") String searchedName);
```

But it doesn't work since `searched_name` is not a Path element.

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

If you append `&format=json` after `?method=search` and use `@Query("name")` then name will be appended after the `format` parameter. If the server is handling the parameters correctly the order shouldn't matter.

i.e.

```
@GET("?method=search&format=json")
Single<List<Album>> getAlbums(@Query("name") String name);
```

Would translate to: `http://myrestapi.com/?method=search&format=json&name=name`

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes it works, but I wanted to know if there is a way to keep the order.